# Unix: command for sudo-mv-chown combo?

Tags: unix, sudo, mv, chown

I am operating as sudo in a system where I mv a great amount of files and dirs to and fro. Is there a command for the combo?

```
$ sudo -i; # mv hello /home/other; # chown -R other:other /home/other/hello
```

Comment: the MYYN: no, what does it do?

Comment: `A && B` executes `B` iff `A` succeeded. If you are writing a system administration script, also consider using `set -e` to abort on errors.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try the [`install`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/install) command (options `-o`, `-g` and `-m`).

Comment: +1. Didn't knew that this existed. Exactly what the OP asked for.

Comment: The OP is doing a `mv`.  `install` is more like a `cp`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ?

```
david@pcdavid:~$ cat zz
whoami
david@pcdavid:~$ sudo -i "cd /home/david; mv zz yy; chown root yy; sh yy"
root
```

Answer (score 0):

Put those commands in a shell script and run the script with sudo.